# Win32 GUI change value with button

Tags: c++, win32gui

I'm working with CSV files. I have little program that shows data with ID, but I need to change ID with button and input field. Right now i can mannualy change int i = #; But I need field, where user enter his number, and then programm show or change data.

```
case WM_PAINT:
    {


        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd,&ps);
        TextOut(hdc,    5,        5,      txt_companyName,    _tcslen(txt_companyName));
        TextOut(hdc,    110,      5,      txt_programName,    _tcslen(txt_programName));
        /* Headers */
        TextOut(hdc,    5,        23,     txt_opened,         _tcslen(txt_opened));
        TextOut(hdc,    250,      23,     txt_time,           _tcslen(txt_time));
        TextOut(hdc,    290+15,   23,     txt_input,          _tcslen(txt_input));
        TextOut(hdc,    428+15,   23,     txt_time,           _tcslen(txt_time));
        TextOut(hdc,    468+25,   23,     txt_timeSpent,      _tcslen(txt_timeSpent));
        TextOut(hdc,    578+25,   23,     txt_timeRemain,     _tcslen(txt_timeRemain));
        /* Data printing in row */

        int i = 3;
        std::string data_component_label = getElementFromFileLine("data.csv",i,8,0);
        std::string data_component_mslLvl = getElementFromFileLine("data.csv",i,8,1);
        std::string data_component_opened = getElementFromFileLine("data.csv",i,8,2);
        std::string data_component_timeOpened = getElementFromFileLine("data.csv",i,8,3);
        std::string data_component_input = getElementFromFileLine("data.csv",i,8,4);
        std::string data_component_timeInput = getElementFromFileLine("data.csv",i,8,5);
        std::string data_component_timeSpent = getElementFromFileLine("data.csv",i,8,6);
        std::string data_component_timeRemain = getElementFromFileLine("data.csv",i,8,7);
        //std::string data_component_Status = getElementFromFileLine("data.csv",2,8,2);


        //TextOut(hdc,    5,        23+18,    data_component_opened,         _tcslen(data_component_opened));
        TextOut(hdc,    5,        23+18,    data_component_opened.c_str(),         _tcslen(data_component_opened.c_str()));
        TextOut(hdc,    250,      23+18,    data_component_timeOpened.c_str(),     _tcslen(data_component_timeOpened.c_str()));
        TextOut(hdc,    290+15,   23+18,    data_component_input.c_str(),          _tcslen(data_component_input.c_str()));
        TextOut(hdc,    428+15,   23+18,    data_component_timeInput.c_str(),      _tcslen(data_component_timeInput.c_str()));
        TextOut(hdc,    468+25,   23+18,    data_component_timeSpent.c_str(),      _tcslen(data_component_timeSpent.c_str()));
        TextOut(hdc,    578+25,   23+18,    data_component_timeRemain.c_str(),     _tcslen(data_component_timeRemain.c_str()));
        EndPaint(hwnd,&ps);
    }
    break;
```

I have a button and input in WM_CREATE and WM_COMMAND, but when I trying to use buffer in WM_PAINT, for example print it in MessageBox, expected a message box with data, user input, however, there is compile error -

> main.cpp|error: 'buffer' was not declared in this scope

so I need somehow get data from WM_COMMAND to WM_PAINT

```
case WM_CREATE:
    {

        hEdit=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
            "EDIT",
            "",
            WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|
            ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
            95,
            80,
            200,
            30,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);
        HGDIOBJ hfDefault=GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
        HWND hWndButton=CreateWindowEx(NULL,
            "BUTTON",
            "NEXT",
            WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            5,
            80,
            75,
            30,
            hwnd,
            (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_BUTTON,
            GetModuleHandle(NULL),
            NULL);

            SendMessage(hWndButton,
                WM_SETFONT,
                (WPARAM)hfDefault,
                MAKELPARAM(FALSE,0));


    }
        break;
case WM_COMMAND:
    switch(LOWORD(wParam))
    {
        case IDC_MAIN_BUTTON:
        {
            char buffer[265];

            SendMessage(hEdit,
                        WM_GETTEXT,
                        sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]),
                        reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(buffer));
```

break;

Comment: This code indicates that each string that you want to present is searched for in a text file, and read from that file, during painting. That's very inefficient. For your modify-data functionality you need (practically) to have this data in some internal data structure. Then handle `WM_COMMAND` for the button click.

Comment: That said, why not use a spreadsheet? If you have Microsoft Excel then you only need convince it to accept your choice of comma or semicolon as delimiter, and choice of comma or period for the fraction separator in numbers. I don't recall, sorry. There's a free spreadsheet in the the Open Office package.

Comment: Also, instead of  `_tcslen(data_component_opened.c_str())` do `data_component_opened.length()`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf , I'm using Libre Office ( also free and opensource ). I don't have problems with show data. It works, as expected, however I need button, which will change variable value. 
I changed some info in subj.